# ListView.builder shows every index, how to show only the one from the statement?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have a simple fetch from an api. But I want to fetch data from only the index that gets passed.
But if I try to put a condition on it, it shows every one that gets fetched. How can I show only the one from the condition?

```
   _isLoading
          ? const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                if(dataFromAPI!.pokemon[index].name==widget.pokemon.name){
                  print(dataFromAPI!.pokemon[index].name);
                  return const Center(child: Text("This is the pokemon!"),);
                }else{
                  return const Text("This is the wrong one");
                }

              },
              itemCount: dataFromAPI!.pokemon.length,
            )
```

[image]

Comment: What if you just filter your data before and use filtered result in your list instead of original one?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do is to
create a function where you will check for the dataFromAPI!.pokemon list and iterate through each item of this list and compare **dataFromAPI!.pokemon[index].name==widget.pokemon.name** and assign the values to a new list e.g (**rightList**).
Use that list in ListView builder.

```
  _isLoading
      ? const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        )
      : ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return const Center(child: Text("This is the pokemon!"),);
          },
          itemCount: rightList.length,
        )
```